# A quicker way to copy/paste in Google Sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working with a sheet to create labels for materials that we use, I have a sheet set up to ask how many labels are needed, then multiple copies are made, then pushed into a tab that follows the label sheet layout.

[Here is the example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1O-aIZwgP7iHk_ULrwftHB8mz7GjjlqK6rnEt_iH6GIY/edit?usp=sharing)

As of now I have a script to take every cell from the example labels sheet and then copy it to the example label clean sheet, then removes any blank rows and blank cells and shifts up. It takes really long and it feels like it is not the best approach to the problem. What is your recommended way to solve this problem for minimal run time?

For reference here is the script I have now:

```
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx").getSheetByName("Example Labels Clean");
  spreadsheet.getRange('A:C').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!A1').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('C1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!A2').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A2').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!A3').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('C2').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!A4').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A3').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!A5').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('C3').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!A6').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A4').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!A7').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('C4').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!A8').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A5').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!A9').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('C5').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!A10').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A6').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!A11').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('C6').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!A12').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A7').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!A13').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('C7').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!A14').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A8').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!A15').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A9').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!A16').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('C9').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!A17').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A10').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!A18').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('C10').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!A19').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A11').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!A20').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('C11').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!A21').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A12').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!A22').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('C12').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!A23').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A13').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!A24').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('C13').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!A25').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A14').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!A26').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('C14').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!A27').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A15').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!A28').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('C15').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!A29').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A16').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!A30').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('C16').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!B1').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A17').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!B2').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('C17').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!B3').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A18').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!B4').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('C18').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!B5').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A19').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!B6').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('C19').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!B7').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A20').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!B8').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('C20').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!B9').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A21').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!B10').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('C21').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!B11').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A22').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!B12').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('C22').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!B13').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A23').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!B14').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('C23').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!B15').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A24').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!B16').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('C24').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!B17').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A25').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!B18').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('C25').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!B19').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A26').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!B20').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('C26').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!B21').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A27').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!B22').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('C27').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!B23').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A28').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!B24').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('C28').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!B25').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A29').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!B26').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('C29').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!B27').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A30').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!B28').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('C30').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!B29').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A31').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!B30').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('C31').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!C1').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A32').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!C2').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('C32').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!C3').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A33').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!C4').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('C33').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!C5').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A34').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!C6').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('C34').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!C7').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A35').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!C8').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('C35').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!C9').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A36').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!C10').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('C36').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!C11').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A37').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!C12').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('C37').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!C13').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A38').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!C14').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('C38').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!C15').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A39').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!C16').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('C39').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!C17').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A40').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!C18').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('C40').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!C19').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A41').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!C20').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('C41').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!C21').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A42').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!C22').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('C42').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!C23').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A43').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!C24').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('C43').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!C25').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A44').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!C26').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('C44').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!C27').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A45').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!C28').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('C45').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!C29').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A46').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!C30').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxxxxxxxxxxxx").getSheetByName("Example Labels Clean");
  var data = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  var targetData = new Array();
  for(n=0;n<data.length;++n)
  {
    if(data[n].join().replace(/,/g,'')!=''){ targetData.push(data[n])};
  }
  sh.getDataRange().clear();
  sh.getRange(1,1,targetData.length,targetData[0].length).setValues(targetData);
  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx").getSheetByName("Example Labels Clean");
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow(); 
  for (var i = 1; i < lastRow+1; i++)
  {
    if((sheet.getRange('A'+(lastRow-i+1)).getValue()) + ""=="")
    {
      sheet.getRange('A'+(lastRow-i+1)).deleteCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS);
    }
    if((sheet.getRange('C'+(lastRow-i+1)).getValue())=="")
    {
      sheet.getRange('C'+(lastRow-i+1)).deleteCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS);
    }
  }
```

Comment: You are not likely to get a good response with this question. Create the simplest, shortest code example that reproduces the problem (MVCE).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Use batch operations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations).

You're already using batch operations once in your program for defining and setting `targetData`. Do the same thing everywhere else:

- Basically all of the individual `copyTo()` calls at the top of your script can be made with a single [**`getValues()`**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) and then [**`setValues()`**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues).
- The individual `getRange()`, `getValue()`, and `deleteCells()` calls in your final for loop can be converted to a batch operation *outside* the loop.
- If "Example Labels Clean" is the same sheet, then you don't need to save it into three separate variables `spreadsheet`, `sh`, and `sheet`.

Also, the `activate()` calls are unnecessary and also slowing the execution. This method is useful for selecting a range in the UI–likely irrelevant for this script.

```
// This is unnecessary 
spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();
spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!A1').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);

// This is preferred
spreadsheet.getRange('Labels!A1').copyTo(spreadsheet.getRange('A1'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
```

Comment: Okay, my question now is getting it to output into the sheet in the proper format for the labels. Which is [data],[blank],[data]. How would I go about that?

Comment: @Index Is that supposed to be a single row of 3 cells where the middle cell is blank? If so, use `null` where it should be blank.

Comment: Yes, that's the format, the code I have now pastes it but in the regular format of 
[data],[data],[data]


`for(n = 0; n < data.length; n++)
  {
    if(data[n] != "")
    {     
      Paste.push(data[n]);
    }
  }
  sheet2.getDataRange().clear();
  sheet2.getRange(1,1,Paste.length,Paste[0].length).setValues(Paste);
 
  Logger.log(Paste);`

How would I get it to add into the sheet in the format I want?

Comment: @Index To be honest, I can't read that with the formatting allowed in comments. This is a separate question anyway, so I suggest you post as another questions with the details relevant to this more specific issue.